# Column not allowed here Oracle SQL on multiple columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to insert records into a table, and I'm getting a "column not allowed here" error on my "item rating column" ("PG" in the example below) when I'm inserting this record:

```
INSERT INTO ITEM VALUES (
item_s1.NEXTVAL
, '786936161878'
, (SELECT common_lookup_id FROM common_lookup 
     WHERE common_lookup_type = 'DVD_WIDE_SCREEN')
, "The Sandlot"
, "American Baseball Classic"
, "PG"
, TO_DATE('1993/04/01 01:00:00', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss')
, 1
, SYSDATE
, 1
, SYSDATE
);
```

But when I take out the "PG", it throws the error on the "American Baseball Classic". 
What's going on here?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF00218

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`PG` is in double quotes, which means it is not a string.  Strings are delimited by single quotes in SQL.  But I would recommend writing this as:

```
INSERT INTO ITEM ( list the columns here)
    SELECT item_s1.NEXTVAL, '786936161878', common_lookup_id, 
          'The Sandlot', 'American Baseball Classic', 'PG',
          TO_DATE('1993/04/01 01:00:00', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'),
          1, SYSDATE, 1, SYSDATE
    FROM common_lookup
    WHERE common_lookup_type = 'DVD_WIDE_SCREEN';
```